# Can I use misput?

Tags: word-choice

Is it common to say "He misput his book in my mailbox/drawer"? If not, should I use misdeliver here? Any other expressions?

Thanks!

Comment: [*Misplaced*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/misplaced) is common.

Comment: Thanks! But is misput ever been used? Yesterday I used misput, the guy I am talking to seems confused.

Comment: 'Misput' is never used, use 'misplaced'.

Comment: Seconded. While technically a valid English word, it's not one I have ever encountered.

Comment: Note that *misplace* has two distinct senses.

Comment: @Watercleave What is a 'technically valid English word'? [quotes to show your terminology in a slightly different form]

Comment: @Jiang You must realise that there can be a big difference between 'what some people consider is actually an English word', 'a word appearing in the OED', 'a word reasonable to use in certain special situations' and 'a word considered normal English by most anglophones'. 'Misput' appears in some dictionaries, but then so do 'jeepable' and 'jaseran'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth A word that can be found in at least one recent, reputable dictionary; in practice, a word which an English teacher or lecturer would be obliged to accept as being an English word, albeit not without the possibility of loss of tone or word choice marks.

Comment: Per the OQ's usage: *accidentally put* is more likely to be said than *misput*.

Comment: @Watercleave What if it's marked 'obsolete'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Misput](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/misput)  is a rare  term meaning:

> - (*dialectal*)
>     1
>     :  misplace
>     2
>     :  disconcert

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=misput%2Cmisdeliver%2Cmisplace&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmisput%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmisdeliver%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmisplace%3B%2Cc0) ( misput, misdeliver, misplace)

The term you probably need is *misplaced*.

Source: www.merriam-webster.com

Comment: Yes, but the OP should understand that there are two senses for *misplace*: one has to do with forgetting where you’ve left something, and the other has to do with a deliberate but incorrect positioning. These are quite different, and the first is much more common than the second. However, it is the second that applies here.